# Does every android device getResource() method return different resources?

Tags: java, android

while working with android resources to convert from dp to pixel I noticed that I need to use the `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density`. This code is where the confusion lies which lead me to my question.

1) Based on the code above, `getResources()` have to return different resources above because otherwise how can the `getDisplayMetrics().density` be able to return different density on different devices. Am I correct in this assumption? or does the `getDisplayMetrics()` return different `DisplayMetrics` on different devices?

2) Also, I thought that `getResources()` return the resources in a device. If so shouldn't I be able to use the method right from the start. By this I mean declare the method as shown

```
   Class mainactivity extends Activity(){ 
     Resources test =getResources()
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(){
      }
    }
```

I declare the method outside the onCreate() method. However, this does not work. the `getResources()` only works when you declare it in the activity lifecycle. Can anyone tell me why I must getResources() in the activity life cycle when `getResources()` should return a device resource as a whole?

If my question is unclear I'll try my best to clarify if you leave  a comment.

Comment: Are you just trying to write code to convert a number in dp (say, in a variable) to a number in px for the device?

Comment: yah that is what my code is above but the confusion lies in the getResources() part like I explain above.

Comment: 1. What are you trying to get at? `Resources` is well-documented, and it seems you're missing something. 2. Is it a problem that you can't `getResources()` outside of the activity lifecycle? If it is, you're using it wrong, as there's nothing you should need from a `Resources` instance outside of a valid context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Android Reference Guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources()) getResources "returns a Resources instance for your application's package" not your device's. So that might be the reason you can't access it outside activity lifecycle. The method getResources actually returns resources under your res directory and getResources.getDisplayMetrics according to [android reference guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDisplayMetrics()) "Return the current display metrics that are in effect for this resource object" which, i think, means the current layout in effect .

Answer (score 0):

You have to call getResources() with the activity lifecycle because the activity isn't "ready" to act like a full Context at the time the object is instantiated.  Android does some additional setup before you can work with it.

You need to get a new instance of Resource with each activity because Resources contains a lot of different things that may be different as the device conditions change.  For example, you may have different layouts for different orientations, or different strings for different languages. Just asks for Resources with each new Activity no earlier than onCreate() and trust that it will access the correct things.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have taken a look at that code and I did used it. However, I am just really confuse about whether the getResources() return different things for different devices cause obviously the density is different for different devices.

Comment: Resources has a lot of different things in it which can change drastically depending on the circumstances of the device. For example, how you you determine which layout resource to use if they're different in landscape and portrait.  Just get a new Resources every time and use for each new Activity instance.